# Strange Character appended in request

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I am using moxieapps Uploader class and have ran into a strange issue.

We have some parameters, one of which identifies folder name where the file is to be uploaded. This parameter is being set using the setPostParams method of Uploader. On file upload completion, a servlet uploads the files in the folder that is already created by the application before hand.

Now, if parameter value that has folder name contains a value with Accent, for example Ã, a non visible character is added next to it when request is received at servlet. Causing a new folder to be created with same name that already exists. On cmd using dir command, a strange character is shown in directory listing. Snapshot attached.

Screenshot of console folder:

[image: Screenshot of console folder]

I have also added the below filter in web.xml

`<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>`

Is there a way I could set character encoding in Uploader class of moxieapps.

Comment: Encoding issue, hard to tell where since you didn't post any code

Comment: Looks like your 2-byte character will be read as two one-byte characters. That's why proper encoding is useful ...

Comment: Yes I did identify it to be an encoding issue. Could not find way to set encoding in the moxieapps Uploader.